# How can I use the + (or =) key in a mapping in vim?

Tags: vim

I wanted to remap (for normal mode) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> but it didn't work.

Is there another way to write this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem using  and  because my shell uses those to resize my window and font size.  I was able to map '+' and '-' to the commands so pressing them in normal mode incremented and decremented values.

```
map + <C-a>
map - <C-x>
```

Is that what you were trying to accomplish?  I don't know if that will work for you, since they probably have different uses that I don't use.

You could also use a [mapleader](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/map.html#%3CLeader%3E) instead of control to do this and not mess with any default uses:

```
let mapleader=","
map <Leader>+ <C-a>
map <Leader>- <C-x>
```

Instead of **C-+** and **C--**, you would use **,+** and **,-**.

Comment: Voted up because of the user of mapleader. The whole point of using Vim is to get away from those damn control buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>, but for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> instead (replace hyphen with underscore).

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```
map <C-a> <C-=>
map <C-=> :echo 'ken'<CR>

map <C-x> <C-->
map <C--> :echo 'barbie'<CR>
```

Then `<C-a>` should echo `ken` and `<C-->` should echo `barbie`

Comment: doesn't work for me and I used the exact mappings you posted... any ideas why?